# Get nth-child and act on it :jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector, css-selectors

The code below only acts upon the last child and it triggers the function for all the other child elements.

```
$('.streetdog').hide();
$('.cat').mouseenter(function(){
    var $catVal = $(".cat").index(this);
    $('.streetdog:nth-child('+$catVal+')').show();
});
```

You can see the demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tunetosuraj/rkM8N/).
Basically I'm trying to trigger the child element of the specific loop and hover of `.cat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:eq` instead of `:nth-child`. Since the `.eq()` is more efficient than `:eq`, use `.eq()` instead:

```
$('.streetdog').hide();
$('.cat').mouseenter(function(){
    var $catVal = $(".cat").index(this);
    $('.streetdog').eq($catVal).show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkM8N/1/

`$('.streetdog').eq()` creates a set consisting of all elements whose classname equals `streetdog`. Then, `.eq(n)` returns the *n*th element in this set.

`$('.streetdog:nth-child(' + $catVal + ')')` select a `.streetdog` element which is the `$catVal`th child of its parent. Hence, the elements are only shown when `$catVal` equals two.

Comment: Well thanks but I would like to know what is the basic difference between `:eq` and `:nth-child`, I searched out some forum , they all said that both are almost same.

Comment: @tunetosuraj - See the jQuery docs for `nth-child` (I've copied the relevant quote into my answer) - http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

A perfectly good answer has already been given, but as an alternative, if your HTML structure is not going to change, you could use `parent` to get up to the parent `div`, and `next` to get the `.streetdog` element:

```
$(".streetdog").hide();
$(".cat").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().show(); 
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rkM8N/4/).

The reason that `eq` works, but `nth-child` does not is explained by the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even
>   though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements.
>   With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class. With :eq(n) only the selector
>   attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of
>   any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.